# Can't run new memory kit at 2400MHz

Tags: memory, motherboard, overclocking

I replaced my old GeIL Enhance CORSA 4x4GB @1600MHz CL9 with this new kit:

- Corsair Vengeance Pro 2x8GB @2400MHz CL11 (Part No. *CMY16GX3M2A2400C1**1***)

I have a ASUS P8H77-V motherboard. I checked its QVL and found out Corsair Vengeance Pro 2x8GB @2400MHz is supported, but with a slightly different part number, which is *CMY16GX3M2A2400C1**0***.

The only difference between CMY16GX3M2A2400C11 and CMY16GX3M2A2400C10 is supported XMP version.

CMY16GX3M2A2400C11 is designed for XMP 1.3, and CMY16GX3M2A2400C10 for XMP 1.2 and my motherboard only supports XMP 1.2

Anyways, I found out too late, and bought the RAM.

After Installation, they ran at default:

- 1333MHz / 9-9-9-24-1T / 1.5v

I managed to run them at:

- 1600MHz / 9-9-9-24-1T / 1.5v

But I couldn’t set them on 2400, 2200, 2000, or 1866MHz. I tried XMP, and also tried setting frequency, timing and voltage manually, but it didn't work.

And here's another thing. When I chose XMP, there was only one profile available, that offered 2200MHz / 11-13-13-31-2T / 1.65v

Is this all because of incompatibility caused by XMP version difference, or am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is the fact that your board doesn't specify that it supports 2400 MHz. Since the clock was too fast, it automatically set it to the lowest supported clock of 1333 MHz. I'm not entirely familiar with XMP, but by enabling it it seems to allow it to run your board at it's max supported frequency of 2200 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your motherboard. I went to ASUS's website and found [this](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H77V/specifications/). I will put the memory section below, but essentially it can only run at a max of 2200 if it's overclocked.  Its standard max speed is 1600MHz, which explains what you were getting.  Unfortunately, 2200 is the fastest you will get out of it, and overclocking can damage your computer if it isn't maintained correctly.  It's not as bad on memory (in some cases), but I should still point that out.  I would suggest to either get cheaper RAM, or let it run at 2200MHz.

- 4 x DIMM, Max. 32GB, DDR3
- 2200(O.C.)/2133(O.C.)/2000(O.C.)/1866(O.C.)/1800(O.C.)/
- 1600/1333 MHz Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory
- Dual Channel Memory Architecture
- Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)
- 1600MHz and higher frequency is supported by Intel® 3rd generation processors.
- Hyper DIMM support is subject to the physical characteristics of individual CPUs.
- Refer to www.asus.com for the Memory QVL (Qualified Vendors Lists).
- Due to OS limitation, when installing total memory of 4GB capacity or more, Windows® 32-bit operation system may only recognize less than 3GB. Install a 64-bit Windows® OS when you want to install 4GB or more memory on the motherboard.
- Due to the CPU behavior, DDR3 2133/1866MHz memory module will run at DDR3 2000/1800MHz frequency as default.

Comment: 2200 is overclocking anyway, so I'm not sure why overclocking to 2200 is OK but overclocking to 2400 is not. Either way it's the processor, not the motherboard, that limits the speed.

Comment: The BIOS on the board will only allow it to be overclocked to 2200 from the manufacturer, that's why they put 2200(O.C.) to be the fastest.  If you want to risk it going faster, you will either need a custom BIOS or find out what the timing and power needs to be set to (not 100% sure there).  I do not overclock, so if you want to find out how to make it go over 2200, check on an overclock forum, since they would know more (not sure how many people here even overclock).

Comment: The BIOS only recognizes XMP presets up to 2200. It allows you to overclock to anything you want. The manual lists 2400 (O.C.) support, presumably with a BIOS update.

Comment: Then I would explore that route, but as far as your original question I answered that (why it wouldn't run at 2400MHz).  If you want to know how to overclock it, I don't know enough to help you there.  From my basic knowledge of it, it is usually in the BIOS, and in some cases requires custom BIOS if the manufacturer's BIOS doesn't allow for the adjustments you need to make.

Comment: This is an ethusiasts/overclocking board, it *will* allow it without any modifications. But as mentioned, there are several BIOS updates that "improve memory compatibility" and stability, which should be tried. But then, there's really negligible difference between 2400 and 2200 anyway